# Artifactory-pro recommendations for upgrade version from 4.14.2 to 5.7

Tags: artifactory

I am planning to upgrade artifactory-pro from 4.14.2 to 5.7. Has anyone done this so far? We use npm, bower, debian, yum repositories. Any recommendation or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As I see it, the upgrade depends on two main factors:

1. Your installation type(ZIP/RPM/RPM OSS/Debian/Docker). [Here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-UpgradingtotheLatestVersion) you can find detailed instructions for each type:

   - [ZIP installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-ZIPInstallation)
   - [RPM installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-RPMInstallation)
   - [RPM OSS installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-RPMOSSInstallation)
   - [Debian installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-DebianInstallation)
   - [Docker installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-DockerInstallation)
2. In case you use an HA cluster, [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+an+Enterprise+HA+Cluster) are the instructions.

While no special operations are required except those are mentioned in the instructions - please pay attention to **updates** and other **special instructions** since there are specific instructions to upgrading from Artifactory 4.x to 5.4.x and above. [As can be seen here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-ZIPInstallation) (for example).

Like in any other upgrade process, make sure you have a [full system backup](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Backups) (Artifactory configuration, metadata, and artifacts)